# XMLHttpRequest and returning PHP file with updated Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I've read all of the similar questions out there, but couldn't find an answer to my question.

I'm using this...

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser-locations.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

...with a dropdown menu to provide a user-selected option for 'q' which is sent to "getuser-locations.php" where I use the 'q' value to run some sql queries to return an updated table, and also update variables within a script for plotting locations on a Google map.

My dropdown "onchange" returns the html from "getuser-locations.php" and updates the table fine, and also returns the html outline of the map, but obviously no Javascript to go inside.

I know this type of request will not execute any Javascript...so my question is, how exactly can I take 'q', update the Javascript in "getuser-locations.php", and return the updated Javascript output? The contents of the map are based off of the user input 'q' so it's important the two files work in conjunction with each other.

Comment: You can load an external JS file programmatically by creating a new script tag (w/`document.createElement`) and setting it's `src` to be the file you want, and that will execute it on the page, but if you're trying to get some dynamically created JS from PHP you might be better off having your PHP return the data in a format that you can play with in JS (i.e. JSON) and place that implementation entirely in your JS.

Comment: Perhaps I could dynamically load my php values into a JS var array on the first page? So I have the Javascript loaded on my main page, then update the JS variable values? Ex: var locations = [ {PHP from getuser-locations.php file}]; I'm not too versed in JS yet so I don't know if something like that'd work...but I'll try @ZachButtram

Comment: Something like that. If you aren't used to using JSON there's no better time to start learning, it's pretty darn ubiquitous. In particular these might help you out: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse